# Dimension of the candela unit: What does J stand for?

Tags: terminology, notation

The **J** symbol can represent the **unit** of energy but it's also the symbol for the **dimension** of the candela (or [luminous intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_intensity)).

For the energy **unit**, it clearly comes from the family name of the English physicist James Prescott **Joule** (1818–1889), but for the luminous intensity **dimension**, what's the origin? What does it stand for?

I'm also asking because the energy **unit** has the **dimension** $\mathsf{L}^2\cdot\mathsf{M}\cdot\mathsf{T}^{-2}$ which doesn't contain the **dimension** of the luminous intensity.

Comment: This is a [history-of-physics question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic).

Comment: @G.Smith Should I re-ask it on physics.meta ? Or can I move it there somehow ?

Comment: I don't think it's standard notation. Did you read [the note there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_intensity#cite_note-note-dimension-symbol-12): «The symbols in this column denote dimensions; "L", "T" and "J" are for length, time and luminous intensity respectively, not the symbols for the units litre, tesla and joule.»?

Comment: @Geremia It is standard notation as you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Base_units).

Comment: No, it doesn’t belong on meta. It is possible that a moderator will migrate it to the History of Science and Mathematics site. If they don’t, and if you don't get a good answer here, then you might want to ask it there.

Comment: The dimension symbol for current is $\textsf I$, presumably because $I$ is also the usual variable used for current in equations. (I have no idea why.) According to the Wikipedia article on [luminous intensity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_intensity), the variable $I_v$ is used to indicate luminous intensity in equations. (“I” for intensity, presumably.) So I speculate that the corresponding dimension symbol is $\textsf J$ because $\textsf I$ was already “taken” as the dimension symbol for current. They just picked the next letter in the alphabet.

Comment: @G.Smith this reminds me of $j$ being used for imaginary unit in electrical engineering...

Comment: See this related [question/answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45487/why-is-the-candela-dimension-j-not-w/122568#122568)

Comment: For what it's worth, the codification of the dimensions of units within the SI (and, with it, the setting of the $\operatorname{dim}(I_\nu) = \mathsf J$ standard), is *extremely* recent, and it was introduced to the SI Brochure in its *eighth* edition, in 2006. The next obvious target to look for are the CGPM resolutions from the period 1998-2006 that codify this as part of the SI, but they're not explicitly mentioned in the brochure.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol for candela is cd according to the NIST's website.

I gather you are mixing the concept of dimensions symbols (M, L, T) with dimensional analysis and energy units. The symbol for the mass dimension is **M**, it can be in any kg, mg, g etc, Length is **L** which can be millimeters, yards, kilometers etc. The dimension symbol for temperature is **$\Theta$**. So what should be the dimensional symbol for candela? It is **J**. *Does it have to anything with Joule? No*. It is by chance that the symbol matches with Joules. The problem is that English has only 26 letters. Have you heard of the pigeonhole principle?

> In mathematics, the pigeonhole principle states that if $n$ items are put into $m$ containers, with $n>m$, then at least one container must contain more than one item. This theorem is exemplified in real life by truisms like "in any group of three gloves there must be at least two left gloves or at least two right gloves"
>
> ─ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

The same applies on symbols and quantities. From the official website of SI Units, this is the list of symbols to be used for these dimensions:
https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/

> [image]

See [the section on base units on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Base_units).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm not mixing the concepts (or at least, I don't think so ;-)), I was actually more wondering why most symbols for dimension are pretty obvious while only this one is not clear and explained nowhere. I guess the correct answer is actually the one given by @G.Smith : "  was already “taken” as the dimension symbol for current. They just picked the next letter in the alphabet."

Comment: Dear maxagaz, In science and history, one cannot rely on casual coincidences, e.g.   I is the symbol for current, J was chosen as the next symbol for candela. No need to rationalize such choices until and unless it is explicitly written by the SI committee. This makes an assumption  someone was sitting and thinking about the symbols sequentially and he/she must have chosen I for current first and then thought what should we choose for candela? For instance, J or sometimes j is used for current density. How can we rationalize this choice?

Comment: I think G. Smith's suggestion should be taken with caution. **I** and **J** are closely linked (they were one letter for many centuries), so that *may* have been the reason rather than the proximity in dictionaries. "**I** was already taken" is solid, but the reason for choosing **J** is speculation until someone finds evidence.

Answer (score -2):

Candela contains the power emitted and the power is energy per sec or Joules/sec. So the J in candela is still Joules.